# Mapboxgl setSyle undefined after creating new map instance

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, mapbox-gl-js

In my units tests in some cases after creating a new instance of `mapboxgl.Map` the method `map.setStyle` is undefined. The unit tests are running angular 1.5 + karma jasmine. Im using the latest version of mapboxgl.

When creating map inside a directive, `map.setStyle` is defined, ex:

```
// directive 
angular.directive('mapDirective', function() {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        ctrl.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: elem[0],
            style: 'mapbox://styles/spmatt/ciksnpcsy004992klvge9h2zb'
        });
        console.log(ctrl.map.setStyle); // defined
    }
});


// tests
let element = angular.element('<map-directive></map-directive>');
this.$compile(element)(this.$rootScope.$new());
this.$rootScope.$digest();

expect(this.vm.map.setStyle).toBeDefined(); // passes
```

When creating in tests, `map.setStyle` is not defined, ex:

```
let element = angular.element('<div></div>');
this.$compile(element)(this.$rootScope.$new());
this.$rootScope.$digest();

map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: element[0],
  style: 'mapbox://styles/spmatt/ciksnpcsy004992klvge9h2zb'
});

expect(map.setSyle).toBeDefined(); // fail
```

The second instance should be working, any ideas why it fails?

Answer (score 0):

What is your testing environment? Some headless browsers doesn't have GL, so MapboxGL won't even be supported.

Take a look and see what `mapboxgl.supported()` returns. I wonder if your map instantiation fails because of this.